# General Relativity in a Differential Geometry concept

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

I know that in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we can define the curvature of a parametrized curve $\textbf{x}(t)=\bigl( x(t), y(t)\bigr)$ as
$$ \kappa(t) = \dfrac{\text{det}(\textbf{x}',\textbf{x}'')}{||\textbf{x}'||^3}.$$
If I use a change of parameter $\overline{t}=\phi(t)$ we can reparametrize the curvature
$$ \boxed{\overline{\kappa}(\overline{t}) =\kappa(t)\equiv \kappa\bigl(\phi(\overline{t})\bigr)}\tag{1}.$$
Equation (1) is the definition of a **scalar**. The curvature is a scalar magnitude.

> My question is: 1. Why is the meaning of the next equation, very similar
>   to equation (1)? 2. In particular, what functions verify the next
>   equations? $$ \overline{\kappa}(t)=\kappa(t) .\tag{2}$$
>   My teacher says that the solution is in a General Relativity book, usually in the 7th or 8th chapter. 3. So what is the General Relativity concept behind the equation (2)?

My opinion: It could be the curvature $\kappa: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of a *geodesic curve* in a surface. The curvature of all curves verify the equation (1), in addition if the curve is a geodesic also verify the equation (2). Indeed, this concept is related to General Relativity.

*Note that equation (2) is not the same that the equation (1).*

I asked the same question in [Mysterious property of the curvature of a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2232464/)

Comment: I've read the question several times, and I can't make out what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

In $(1)$, the new curvature $\bar{\kappa}$ and the old curvature $\kappa$ are evaluated at different corresponding values of the coordinate. Say you have your curve $\mathbf{x}(t)$, which you used to calculate $\kappa(t)$, and you make a reparametrization $\bar{t} = 2t$. The first equation says that if you use this new parametrization to calculate $\bar\kappa$ at $\bar t = 2$, you'll get the same value as if you calculated $\kappa$ at $t=1$, because $t=1$ is the same point of the curve as $\bar t = 2$. This is pretty straightforward: if you change your parameter, the same point of the curve will have different values of the parameter, and the curvature is a scalar: it just depends on where you are on the curve, not on your coordinate.

In $(2)$, notice how it says $t$ in both sides. Now we're saying that the curvature won't change if you calculate it using both parametrizations but using **the same** value of the coordinate, not **corresponding** values like earlier. To reuse our example, this equation says that $\bar \kappa$ evaluated at $2$ should give the same value as $\kappa$ evaluated at $2$, not at $1$ like before.

The first important thing to say is that *this is not necessarily true*. Equation $(1)$ says that the curvature is a scalar and it is always true, but equation $(2)$ is a property that may or may not hold, depending on your curve and the transformation. This is similar but not exactly the same as an isometry,  meaning a rigid movement: the curve has some symmetry which allows us to change coordinates while the curvature looks the same. The same concept is used in GR, just in more dimensions.

---

Let's do an example. Let's take a parabola as our curve: $x(t) = t, y(t) = t^2$. The curvature ends up being

$$\kappa(t) = \frac{2}{(1+4t^2)^{3/2}}.$$

For example, $\kappa(1) \approx 0.18$. If we change to $\bar t = 2t$, we get a new function

$$\bar \kappa (\bar t) = \frac{2}{(1+\bar t^2)^{3/2}}.$$

Notice that as functions of their arguments, $\bar \kappa$ and $\kappa$ are different, but if you evaluate them at arguments such that $\bar t = 2t$, they give the same result: $\bar \kappa(4) = 0.18 = \kappa(2)$. However, there is no relation between $\bar \kappa(2)$ and $\kappa(2)$. But if we define $t' = -t$, the curvature is the same function of $t'$ as it was of $t$. Now we will have identities like $\kappa'(2) = \kappa(2)$. This is because the transformation we did is a symmetry of the parabola: it corresponds to flipping it around its axis. If our curve was a circle, then any transformation would preserve the curvature, because the curvature is constant.

Comment: Thank you @Javier. The question 1 will be answer if we can connect the equation (2) with some important concept in Differential Geometry, and question 3 in General Relativity. And question 2 if we say the name of the family of function that verify equation (2). The examples only make us to understand the equation (2) but not to go deeper.

Comment: @ClareFrancis as far as I know, there's no particular name for this. A transformation that leaves distances invariant is called an isometry and it appears in GR, but we're talking about leaving the curvature invariant, which doesn't imply being an isometry, though it's related. Also it's not clear what you mean by function: do you mean the curve, or the reparametrization?

Comment: Maybe it could be the "Ricci scalar" or "Curvature scalar" $R$. In fact, this concept appears in the chapter 8 of the famous book "Gravitation" of Misner, Thorne and Wheeler. So, $$ R\bigl( u^\alpha \bigr) = \overline{R} \bigl( u^\alpha \bigr),$$ or something like that.

Comment: @ClareFrancis yes, $\kappa$ is the curvature, but I don't know if a curvature-preserving transformation has any particular name. I'm also not clear what your question is.

Comment: Does Ricci scalar verify the equation (2)? And how?

Comment: @ClareFrancis everything I said applies to the Ricci scalar. Under a general coordinate transformation, $(1)$ applies. $(2)$ applies for specific curvatures and transformations, not in general. You can't say whether the scalar verifies $(2)$ unless you know the specific spacetime and transformation.

Comment: Thanks @Javier for your answer. What about the "Gaussian curvature", $K$? Since $R=2K$, then $$ \overline{K}\bigl(u^\alpha(t)\bigr) = K\bigl( u^\beta(t)\bigr)$$ between a plane and a cylinder but not between a plane and a sphere. Is it correct?

Comment: @ClareFrancis A plane indeed has the same curvature (zero) as a cylinder, but you can't get from one to the other with a reparametrization, because they aren't diffeomorphic. Also, please don't ask multiple questions in the comments. If I haven't answered your original question, edit your post to clarify. If I have, mark as accepted and ask further questions separately.

Comment: The $\kappa$ appears to be calculated incorrectly. Assume a unit speed curve $\alpha(s)=\bigl( x(s),y(s)\bigr)$. Then $T=(x^{'},y^{'})$, and in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, $N$ is defined by rotating  $T$ by $90^{\circ}$ - or $N=(-y^{'},x^{'})$. Hence $\kappa=T^{'} \cdot N.$ 

The OP's normal is $N=(x{''},y{''})$. 
And if $\text{det}(\textbf{x}',\textbf{x}'')$ is equivalent to $\text{det}\langle \textbf{x}',\textbf{x}''\rangle$, where $\langle \textbf{x}',\textbf{x}''\rangle$ is the inner product - the result of det appears to be $0$ - since it's a single number - hence $\kappa=0$  for all curves.